# ADODB : Number of modified records with parameterized query

Tags: delphi, ado, adodb

I use ADODB in Delphi 7 and, for UPDATE queries, I get the number of modified records with TADOConnection Execute procedure "recordsAffected" variable.
like this :

```
 MyConnexion.Execute(sReq, iResReq, [eoExecuteNoRecords]);
```

Where `iResReq` is the modified records number.

Now I want to use parameterized queries with  parameterized SQL like :

```
SQL.Add('UPDATE TABLE SET NAME="TEST" WHERE NAME=:PARAM);
Parameters.ParamByName('PARAM').text:='Smith';
```

but I don't really know how to find the modified record count.
In addition to my question do you know a good tuto about ADODB parameterized queries ?

Comment: Very Good ! I did'nt realize that ExecSQL is a FUNCTION and return the number of modified records.

Comment: As Mikael pointed in his answer, [TADOCommand](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOCommand) is more suitable for this purpose. [TADOQuery.ExecSQL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOQuery.ExecSQL) internally calls the [TADOCommand.Execute](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOCommand.Execute) from its ancestor, [TCustomADODataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TCustomADODataSet). So I would prefer [TADOCommand](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOCommand) ;)

Comment: Ok, I have a working answer. But the 'good' choice among 'TADOCommand.execute', 'TADOQuery.execSQL'... in not evident.

Comment: Hard to say what you are going to do with that DB access object later on. If you want to use it also for some data fetching then the `TADOQuery` is the "right" choice. If you want it only for queries which doesn't return any data (like INSERTs, UPDATEs, CREATEs) then the `TADOCommand` is the "right" one. As I mentioned in my comment before, `TADOQuery` uses `TADOCommand` internally at `ExecSQL` function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a TADOCommand you can do something like this.

```
var
    RecordsAffected: Integer;
begin
    ADOCommand1.CommandText := 'UPDATE TABLE SET NAME="TEST" WHERE NAME=:PARAM';
    ADOCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('PARAM').Value:='Smith';
    ADOCommand1.Execute(RecordsAffected, EmptyParam);
```

It is also possible to do with a TADOQuery if you use ExecSQL (as mentioned by [TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) in comment).

Comment: You are right my code is wrong (I'll edit it )! CommandText allows parameters ?

Comment: @Mikael, you can use TADOQuery to execute an update statement, +1 anyway ;)

Comment: @TLama - You are right. Just tested. Update to answer will happen soon :).

Comment: What is "EmptyParam"?

Comment: @WarrenP Have a look at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Variants.EmptyParam

Comment: Great!  Love this quote from the docwiki: "Marshaling interfaces also exist under Linux, but we can't spare the resources to document them right now."... That must have been written during the Kylix era.